# How to set floating point format for JAXB (json using eclipse moxy)

Tags: java, json, jaxb, moxy

I have a simple pojo class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public static class MyClass {
  private double f; //[0-1]

  @XmlAttribute
  //@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FixedFloatingPointXmlAdapter.class) <-- has issues
  public double getF() {
    return f;
  }
}
```

field f holds values in the range [0,1], which can sometimes be small. I'd like to avoid seeing things like 1.234E-7 (scientific notation) and would like to set the format used to print field f.

I've seen other answers that suggest using an XmlAdapter for this, like so:

```
public class FixedFloatingPointXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Double> {
  private static final DecimalFormat FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("0.00000000");

  @Override
  public Double unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    return v == null ? null : Double.parseDouble(v);
  }

  @Override
  public String marshal(Double v) throws Exception {
    return v == null ? null : FORMAT.format(v);
  }
}
```

but the problem with this is that the value would be printed out as a json **STRING** (so `"0.25000000"` instead of `0.25000000`) - because the XmlAdapter returns a String (not because FORMAT places quotes. it doesnt)

is there any JAXB/moxy annotation that would allow me to control the formatting without turning the field into a json string?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but have you tried trimming the result string FORMAT.format(v), so that NO quotes in the string are returned? What gives FORMAT.format(v) as a result string?  I'm not sure if this is a JAXB problem. You're right about using an XmlAdapter if you have a complexType. For simpleType, use <jaxb:baseType> with parseMethod/printMethod instead. See JAXB 2.2 specs Chapter 7.8.2 for an example.

Comment: since the xml adapter is a Double --> String one the result it then printed as a string. its nor quoted by FORMAT, its quoted bye the general mechanism (because after the adapter its a string, not a number)

Comment: Have you tried the other approach, using the parseMethod/printMethod? See here for and example: https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_different_datatypes.html

Comment: i dont have any xml descriptor files in my project, and would like to leave it annotation-based if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is using [transformation annotations](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts007.htm) of `EclipseLink MOXy`.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlTransformation;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlWriteTransformer;

@XmlRootElement
public static class MyClass {
  @XmlAttribute
  @XmlReadTransformer(transformerClass=FixedFloatingTransformer.class)
  @XmlWriteTransformer(xmlPath="@f", transformerClass=FixedFloatingTransformer.class)
  private double f; //[0-1]

  public double getF() {
    return f;
  }
}
```

Here is the implementation of `transformerClass`.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractTransformationMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.AttributeTransformer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.FieldTransformer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Record;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;

public class FixedFloatingTransformer implements FieldTransformer, AttributeTransformer { 
  private AbstractTransformationMapping mapping;
  private static DecimalFormat FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("0.00000000");

  public Object buildAttributeValue(Record r, Object obj, Session arg2) {
    return r.get(mapping.getFields().get(0));
  }

  public Object buildFieldValue(Object instance, String xpath, Session session) {
    Object o2 = mapping.getAttributeValueFromObject(instance);
    if (o2 instanceof Number) {
      return ((DecimalFormat)FORMAT.clone()).format((Number)o2);
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void initialize(AbstractTransformationMapping mapping) {
    this.mapping = mapping;
  }
}
```

### Update in 2016/12/13

The `@XmlSchemaType` are referenced when `moxy` unmarshal the object to JSON string.
If the `name` is `boolean` or `number type`, `moxy` will outputed the value string without quoted char.

> Sample 1: You have to set formated value to `f`.

```
public static class MyClass {
  private String f;

  @XmlAttribute
  @XmlSchemaType(name="double")
  public String getF() {
    return f;
  }
}
```

> Sample 2 : Add extra getter to return formatted value.

```
public static class MyClass {
  private double f;

  @XmlTransient //preventing the mapping
  public double getF() {
    return f;
  }

  @XmlAttribute(name="f")
  @XmlSchemaType(name="double")
  public String getFAsString() {
    return new DecimalFormat("0.00000000").format(f);
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a variant of this answer. the answer as-is returns a String from `buildFieldValue()`, which results in the string being quoted by marshalling code. however, i ended up returning `class FormattedDouble extends Number`, and put a `toString()` method in that class. attempting to set the field directly to type `FormattedDouble` resulted in an exception from moxy that I think is a bug

Comment: What you said is right. I get another solution when I test your implementation. Please refer the updated answer.